# Error [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request / from localhost:8000 to http://localhost:4000 (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, gatsby

Developing a Gatsby App using this Starter 
https://github.com/the-road-to-react-with-firebase/react-gatsby-firebase-authentication

I keep getting this HPM Error after updated my node packages when I try to visit my page after running Gatsby Develop. The project compiles successfully but then I get this error in the browser and nothing shows up.

> error occurred while trying to proxy to: localhost:8000/

and this in the terminal:

> error [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request / from localhost:8000 to http://localhost:4000 (ECONNREFUSED

once I remove this from the
`gatsby-config.js` file it works and the pages generated in the browser:

```js
module.exports = {
    developMiddleware: app => {
        app.use(
            proxy({
                target: "http://localhost:4000",
            })
        )
    },
}
```

However, I then get this error in the terminal:

> Error loading a result for the page query in "/404.html". The query was not run and no cached result was found.
>   Page not found /404.html

I want to know why isn't the Proxy working and what is the above module exports really doing anyway. I feel like this workaround I'm doing isn't good. Any help or advice would be great!!

Github Repo:

[GitHub Repo for The project](https://github.com/thelovesmith/Island-Stream-Web-MVP)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That error means there's nothing running at `http://localhost:4000`. There seems to be a few problem with your setup:

First, your `developMiddleware` setup points to `http://localhost:4000`, but your server (`server.js`) by default runs at `http://localhost:3000`. Perhaps you forgot to startup the server, or start it up at the wrong port?

Second, if I read it correctly,in your proxy middleware, you're proxying every route to port 4000? This will render Gatsby useless. Here's an example of a better proxy setup:

```
module.exports = {
  developMiddleware: app => {
    app.use(
      "/api",
      proxy({
        target: "http://localhost:4000",
      })
    )
  },
}
```

With this, only request to `localhost:8000/api` will be proxied to `localhost:4000`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Derek def helped out. I just confused myself when updating my packages and refactoring the code. Server us running and the proxy is working.

Answer (score 11):

Try to replace "localhost" by "127.0.0.1"

Comment: That actually did it :) For some reason i need to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in proxy.conf.json, nothing else worked, not even uncommenting 127.0.0.1 localhost in "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" in Windows

Comment: The reason is that I only get an IPv6 address from my Internet provider (translation is done by them) so localhost is bound to ::1 via DNS64

Comment: worked for me too, and after it worked, I understood why. Host file needs IP configuration of routing mentioned. In my host file I had changed it few weeks back and I had forgotten about it. Once this solution worked, I realized, went back to host file to revert back the change, and now it works with even localhost:4800

Comment: originally I had localhost with node20 but then I downgraded to node18 and had to change to 127.0.0.1

Comment: I needed this answer on a non-Gatsby, default VS Angular 16 + NET Core 8  New Project created from Visual Studio, in early 2024.  karma.conf.js was being invoked when invoking F5/debug on the default solution and the error stopped when I changed two references to localhost in the karma.conf.js to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 4):

I did have same error ECONNREFUSED while trying to debug both Angular and Node.js with VS Code and WSL2 Ubuntu-20.04 environment. Apparently that was solved by adding deprecated useWSL flag

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Node Express via NPM",
  "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
  "useWSL": true,
  "runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "node:debug"],
  "port": 9229
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. In my case, I forgot to run  npm run server first.
This will start the server.

Then run npm start in another terminal window.

npm start will call "ng serve  --proxy-config ./proxy.json"

My proxy.json file:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:9000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```