# Error: The func task detection didn't contribute a task for the following configuration

Tags: angular, azure, visual-studio-code

Step 13 of this [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/shift-nodejs-express-apis-serverless/3-exercise-setup) says "Select Debug Express and Angular from the dropdown list and press F5 to start the debugger." Pressed F5 got

```
Error: The func task detection didn't contribute a task for the following configuration:
{
    "type": "func",
    "command": "host start",
    "problemMatcher": "$func-watch",
    "isBackground": true,
    "dependsOn": "npm build",
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/functions"
    }
}
```

Believe it meant tasks.json, line 34. This is a [MS code](http://git%20clone%20https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-module-shifting-nodejs-express-apis-to-serverless%20learn-functions) project of Angular + Node/Express. Caused breakpoint at API being unbound, Terminal shows

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/vacations/ 
from localhost:4200 
to http://localhost:7070 (ECONNREFUSED) 
(https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

How to config the `task`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Error: The func task detection didn't contribute a task for the
> following configuration:
> {
> "type": "func",
> "command": "host start",
> "problemMatcher": "$func-watch",
> "isBackground": true,
> "dependsOn": "npm build",
> "options": {
> "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/functions"
> }
> }

You have to restart VSCode when you change tasks.json. After restart, all can work fine. [Here is a similar discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24796#issuecomment-297034131), Please refer  [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/58836) to fix the error

> [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/vacations/
> from localhost:4200
> to http://localhost:7070 (ECONNREFUSED)
> (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

The above error means there's nothing running at `http://localhost:4000`. There seems to be a few problems with your setup:

First, your `developMiddleware` setup points to `http://localhost:4000,` but your server (server.js) by default runs at `http://localhost:3000`. Perhaps you forgot to startup the server, or start it up at the wrong port?

Second, if I read it correctly, in your proxy middleware, you're proxying every route to port 4000? This will render Gatsby useless. Here's an example of a better proxy setup:

```
module.exports = {
    developMiddleware: app => {
        app.use(
            "/api",
            proxy({
                target: "http://localhost:4000",
            })
        )
    },
}
```

With this, only request to `localhost:8000/api` will be proxied to `localhost:4000`

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56822189)